# Assign an array of numbers to an array of variables

Tags: variable

I have a huge array of variables like this.

```
variables=Flatten[Join[
 Flatten[Table[
    alpha[i, j, k, l, m, n], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 
     2}, {m, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    beta[i, j, k, l, m, n], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}, {k, 0, 1}, {l, 0, 
     1}, {m, 0, 1}, {n, 0, 1}]], {gamma}]]
```

I have an array of values, for the example let's take:

```
values=Flatten[Join[
 Flatten[Table[
    1, {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}, {l, 0, 
     2}, {m, 0, 2}, {n, 0, 2}]], 
  Flatten[Table[
    1, {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}, {k, 0, 1}, {l, 0, 
     1}, {m, 0, 1}, {n, 0, 1}]], {gamma}]]
```

How can I assign each one of my variables inside my array corresponding values from values?

If I do `variables=values`, it will not set values to the alpha's or beta's but it will just change the variable "variables".

How can I say to mathematica to change the values of the variables alpha's and beta's stored in "variables" to affect them the value "1".

I could do a loop but I think there is a better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`variables` itself is a variable. When you do `variables=values`, you simply assign a value to it. You have to assign values to each of its elements. Something like as you suggested

```
Do[variables[[n]] = values[[n]], {n,Length[variables]}]
```

A better way is using `MapThread` which map elements from each array.

```
MapThread[(#1 = #2) &, {variables, values}]

alpha[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

> 1

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this:

```
Inner[Set, Most@variables, Most@values, None];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear[alpha, beta, gamma]
Evaluate[variables] = values;
```

If the variables are still symbols with no value assigned the first line can be left out.